# environmental variable not carrying through on docker compose python example

Tags: docker-compose

I'm having trouble understanding environmental variables in docker compose.  It seems like you can set env variables in a container like this: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers

But when I try I can only set env vars in the docker file - not the compose file.  I'd like to set it in the compose file because a lot of examples show env vars in the compose file (like the tutorial in the docker desktop).  And while it works on the node example in the docker desktop tutorial - it doesn't work for the simplest example I can come up with for python.

Compose file...

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  python-test:
    container_name: mypython-contianer
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: SimpleDockerfile
    environment:
      - SHAPE=SQUARE


    env_file: docker.env
```

Docker file "SimpleDockerfile"

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV FONT=SERIF
RUN python main.py
```

Python file

```
import os
import sys
from pprint import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(dict(os.environ))
    sys.exit(1)
```

When I run

```
 docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit
```

I get the following output

```
 > [4/4] RUN python main.py:
#9 0.755 {'FONT': 'SERIF',
...OTHER STUFF...
#9 0.755  'HOME': '/root',
#9 0.755  'LANG': 'C.UTF-8',
#9 0.755  'PYTHON_PIP_VERSION': '22.0.4',
#9 0.755  'PYTHON_SETUPTOOLS_VERSION': '57.5.0',
#9 0.755  'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.8.13'}
```

Why does FONT variable show up but not SHAPE?

Answer (score 0):

Digging further into the docs of https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment

```
    Note

    If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in
 environment are not automatically visible during the build. 
Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables.
```

The run command in the questions dockerfile I suppose is part of the build - not part of the run.  Changing the dockerfile to..

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV FONT=SERIF
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

I get the following output...

```
Recreating mypython-contianer ... done
Attaching to mypython-contianer
mypython-contianer | {'FONT': 'SERIF',
...MORE STUFF...
mypython-contianer |  'SHAPE': 'SQUARE'}
mypython-contianer exited with code 1
```